# calculate the end of months between two dates in dax

Tags: ssas, dax, powerbi-desktop

I want to calculate the end of months between two dates. For example, if I start with `2019/11/1` and end with `2020/6/30`
I want : `30/11 , 30/12,........, 30/6`

I wrote

```
       EndofCurrentMonth = EOMONTH(testdates[LastDateCurrentYear],1) 
       EndofCurrentMonth = EOMONTH(testdates[LastDateCurrentYear],1)
```

please any help ??
I wrote also this code : but it gives an error

```
      Datesbetween( CALENDAR (DATE(2019,12,1), DATE(2019,11,31)) 
      ,testdates[FirstDayCYR],testdates[EndofCurrentMonth])
```

The cube is already done, I want to build a report using power bi report builder , and I want to compare the sales in the end of the month and make it dynamically, my year begins on 1 NOV

Comment: if i have two dates input (1/12/2018),(30/5/2019),the output will be 30/12,30/1,28/2,......

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
FILTER (
    CALENDAR ( DATE ( 2019, 11, 1 ), DATE ( 2020, 6, 30 ) ),
    EOMONTH ( [Date], 0 ) = [Date]
)
```

Comment: What is [date] evaluate for ?!

Comment: @AhmedNagyDewair [date] is the column name of the list of dates returned by the CALENDAR function.

Comment: It's the same column. The filter criteria specifies to only keep the [date] values which are the last day of each month. Try to execute the code as a new table and you'll see.